# C - Pointer + 1 Meaning

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What the codes basically do is to print the address of each element in the int and char arrays pointed to by pointers i and ch.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *ch;
    int *i;
    int ctr;

    ch = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    i = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

    printf("Index\ti Address\tch Address\n\n");

    for(ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%p\t%p\n",ctr,i+ctr,ch+ctr);
    }

    getch(); 
    return  0;
}
```

Result:

```
Index   i Address       ch Address

0       00511068        00511050
1       0051106C        00511051
2       00511070        00511052
3       00511074        00511053
4       00511078        00511054
5       0051107C        00511055
6       00511080        00511056
7       00511084        00511057
8       00511088        00511058
9       0051108C        00511059
```

I understand that each element in two arrays occupies space size of their data type. My problem is, I'm confused to this operation:

```
i+1
```

If `i` is 00511068 , then `i+1` is `00511069` as opposed to the result. What does `i+1` means? How do you read it? I think I don't fully understand pointer. Please help me understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah, yes, that old chestnut. There's a bit of magic going on when you add N to a pointer; the compiler intuits that you want the address of the Nth item, and multiplies the offset by the size of the datatype.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "magic", it's just the way arithmetic on pointers is defined.

Comment: There are times I'd call it annoying

Answer (score 12):

This is because `int` is 4 bytes on this system. So `+1` on a pointer will increment it by 4 instead of just 1.

When you increment a pointer, you increment it by it's actual size and not the pointer value itself.

Comment: That's what I thought...  But why is that? Isn't odd that `i+1`? How do you read it then? How does it know how much to add instead of just one?

Comment: Another way of seeing it: by doing i+1 you actually increment the pointer to point to next int -which means incrementing the pointer address by 4 as you said-. This is automatically done by the compiler. That's why types exist. It's definitely not odd, but highly useful and logical.

Comment: @domanokz: That's why you have pointers of different types. In general, doing pointer arithmetic on a `sometype *p` pointer offsets it by `sizeof(sometype)`, not by `1`.

Comment: @blagovest-buyukliev Thank you for additional info. I was thinking of the use of data type for pointers before.

Answer (score 5):

`pointer + j` is the same as `&(pointer[j])`, so its the adress of the j:th element in the array pointed to by `pointer`. 
Obviously, a pointer to a large data type will be incremented more than a pointer to a small data type.